# pytesseract unable to recognize complex math formula from image

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, image-processing

I am using **pytesseract** module in python, **pytesseract** recognizes text from image but it **dosen't work on images that contain complex math formulas like under-root, derivation, integration math problem or equation**.

code 2.py

```
# Import modules
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2

# Include tesseract executable in your path
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Create an image object of PIL library
image = Image.open('23.jpg')

# img = cv2.imread('123.jpg')
# pass image into pytesseract module

# pytesseract is trained in many languages
image_to_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng+equ')

image_to_text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)

# Print the text
print(image_to_text)
# print(image_to_text1)


# workon digits
```

Output:

```
242/33
2x

2x+3X

2X+3x=4

2x?-3x +1=0
(x-1)(x+1) =x2-1
(x+2)/((x+3)(x-4))

7-4=3
V(x/2) =3

2xx—343=6x—3 (x#3)

Jeeta =e* +e

dy 2
S=2?-3
dz ¥

dy = (a? — 3)dx
```

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WEQl.jpg)

Comment: Please add some sample Images and some sample code.

Comment: This is a wrapper over [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract]). As soon as you have installed it already, have you tried in cli ?

 And anyway, it is quite common case, ORC tools do not recognize everything.

Comment: @Sameer  i am attach my  code and output, some math equations can not be detect properly. what can i do? thank you in advanced.

Comment: @yvs link didn't work sir.

Comment: @SumitPatel  sorry, use this one:  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Comment: So, yes, you have already installed tesseract . "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe". And now you just can test it without python wrapper, just via cli. Tesseract has --list-lang option.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and so far it doesn't work.  Sometimes it works but most of the time it doesn't even recognize plus and minus signs

Answer (score 6):

To work with MATH language you should install the proper language for tesseract. In your case it is 'equ' from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/3.04.00/equ.traineddata . The full list of available languages is described at https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files

I'm not familiar with tesseract language install for windows. But there is a documentation at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki :

> If you want to use another language, download the appropriate training
>   data, unpack it using 7-zip, and copy the .traineddata file into the
>   'tessdata' directory, probably C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata

And at first try to process your image with cli only ( without pyhton ), because cli has a full list of the options to tune.

Answer (score 0):

I used this Code and it worked!

```
import re
import cv2
import pytesseract as tess
path = (r"C:\Users\10\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe")
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path


png = "Downloads/m.png"
text = tess.image_to_string(png)
text.replace(" ", "")
pattern = re.compile("([0-9][=+-/*])")
equations = [x for x in text if bool(re.match(pattern, x))]

print(re.findall(r'(.*)', str(text))[0])
```