# Extract numpy matrix from pdf

Tags: python, pdf

here is  given screenshot from one of the linear algebra book
[image]

my goal is to extract  matrix  (3x4 size)  using python -this book is pdf, i have  done a lot of  research  and  with help of various  web pages, i come accross  to this solution

```
import PyPDF2
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
# reader =PyPDF2.PdfReader("linear_algebra.pdf")
pdf =pdfplumber.open("linear_algebra.pdf")
# print(reader.pages[25].extract_text())
print(pdf.pages[25].extract_text())
```

result is this :

```
4 SystemsofLinearEquations
term. For clarity, the constants are separated by a vertical line. The augmented matrix is just a different
way ofdescribingthesystemofequations. Thearray ofcoefficients ofthevariables
3 2 1 1
−
2 0 1 2
 − 
3 1 2 5
 
1
−
iscalled thecoefficient matrix ofthesystemand 0 iscalled theconstantmatrix ofthesystem.
 
2
 
Elementary Operations
```

i just took small  fragment, as you see  matrix is not well  formatted :

```
3 2 1 1
−
2 0 1 2
 − 
3 1 2 5
```

what additional paramaters should i do in order to extract full data? also why  −  this line is shown?

Edited : after several experiment, i come up to following solution :

```
import PyPDF2
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# reader =PyPDF2.PdfReader("linear_algebra.pdf")
pdf =pdfplumber.open("linear_algebra.pdf")
# print(reader.pages[25].extract_text())
text =pdf.pages[25].extract_text()
text_list =text.split('\n')[3:8]
# print(text_list)
new_array =[]
for  line in text_list:
    # print(line=='−')
    # print(line=='\uf8ee − \uf8f9')
    if line=='−' or  line=='\uf8ee − \uf8f9':
        continue
    new_array.append(line)
print(len(new_array))
finnal_matrxi =[[ 0 for i in range (4)] for j in range (3)]
print(finnal_matrxi)
for  i in range(len(new_array)):
    temp_text =new_array[i].split(' ')
   # print(temp_text)
    numbers=[int(j) for j in temp_text]
    finnal_matrxi[i]=numbers
print(np.array(finnal_matrxi))
```

result is :

```
3
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[3 2 1 1]
 [2 0 1 2]
 [3 1 2 5]]
```

as you see  negative sign is lost, besides it will not be flexible  everytime make  a such experiment, does not there exist such library which extracts numpy array from pdf?

Comment: Side note: PyPDF2 is deprecated and the project is now called [pypdf](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/meta/history.html)

Comment: for an OCR [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097575/pytesseract-unable-to-recognize-complex-math-formula-from-image)